# Would a vaccine made for humans work on animals who can get the same virus?

Tags: covid-19, virus

Recently it has been reported some dogs and cats getting covid-19. This doesnt seem to be so common I suppose, since we only hear about a few cases but I'm assuming they can transmit the virus anyway. I know there are several techniques for developing vaccines, but anyway, how would this work? Could any vaccine developed for humans work on animals who gets the same virus? None would work? All would work? Is there any info about vaccines developed for humans working in animals who gets the same virus?

Comment: Hi Pablo, is there any literature pointing toward animal to human transmission?

Comment: This may be? https://jvi.asm.org/content/94/7/e00127-20

Comment: This study is related to "immunization of horses with the receptor-binding domain of the viral Spike glycoprotein" https://ri.conicet.gov.ar/handle/11336/109721